# javascript select input value filled by a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input that I fill, using an ajax, with a string.

```
<input type="hidden" name="uploaded_file" value="" />
```

I would like to pick the value of this input once it is filled.

```
var target = $("input[name='uploaded_file']");
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "myurl.php",
    success: function(response) {
        target.val(response) 
    }
})
```

I would like to pick the value of this input once it is filled.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden): *"Note: The input and change events do not apply to this input type. Hidden inputs cannot be focused even using JavaScript (e.g. hiddenInput.focus())."*

Comment: This seems like the wrong way to do things, but you could fire a change event when you change the value (e.g if you set the value like this `input.value = "..."`, change it to `input.value = "..."; input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))`

Comment: Please post your code and help us reproduce your problem. Always refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please tag jquery, since this code uses jquery

Comment: Try putting `var target = $("input[name='uploaded_file']");` in the success function. The element might not exist yet when the JavaScript is executed.